# How do I ensure final output shape matches input shape for a semantic segmentation task?

Tags: neural-network, keras, cnn, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I trying to replicate the semantic segmentation example
https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/
but train on my own data. I have 8 labels (7 features + background). My images are 775 by 770 pixels.

I changed num_classes to 8, img_size to (775,770) (and changed the input and target directories), otherwise I run the example code exactly. When I fit the model, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 14
     12 # Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
     13 epochs = 50
---> 14 model.fit(
     15     train_dataset,
     16     epochs=epochs,
     17     validation_data=valid_dataset,
     18     callbacks=callbacks,
     19     verbose=2,
     20 )
ValueError: in user code:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 775, 770, 1) and (None, 784, 784, 8) are incompatible
```

The model's final output shape is (None, 784, 784, 8).

This is my first foray into neural networks, and I am hoping to learn about functionality and architecture from this example. Explicit instructions, e.g., of the form "You should one-hot encode your labels, do this by..." would be most helpful.

Where am I going wrong? What else should I change in the model to match the size of my inputs and the number of classes?